# XDocument Load - cannot open

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, rss

I'm trying to load rss feed by XDocument.
The url is:

> http://www.ft.com/rss/home/uk

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(url);
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
Cannot open 'http://www.ft.com/rss/home/uk'. The Uri parameter must be a file system relative or absolute path.
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear : `The Uri parameter must be a file system relative or absolute path` It cannot be an http url bu a file path

Comment: @Cieja, I didn't notice the core tag.  You are correct that XmlTextReader isn't there.  If there is a core-compliant substitute that would do the trick.  I've deleted my answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: There is  asp.net-core tag.

Answer (score 1):

`XDocument.Load` does not take URL's, only files as stated in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181(v=vs.110).aspx).

Try something like the following code which I totally did not test:

```
using(var httpclient = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await httpclient.GetAsync("http://www.ft.com/rss/home/uk");
    var xDoc = XDocument.Load(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
}
```